# limits of sequences exponential and factorial: $a_n=e^{5\cos((\pi/6)^n)}$ and $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Compute the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ for the following sequences:

(a) $a_n=e^{5\cos((\pi/6)^n)}$

(b) $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

For part (a) do I just take the limit of the exponent part and then the answer would be $e$ raised to whatever the limit is?

And would the limit be $1$ or $-1$? because $\cos$ goes between those two.

For part $b$ it is in the form of infinity over infinity but how do you take the derivative of $n!$? Will it ever break out of infinity over infinity?

Comment: $(\pi/6^n)$ has limit $0$, the cos therefore has limit $1$, and the whole thing has limit $e^5$.

Comment: For the second one. $\dfrac{n \cdot n-1 \cdots 1}{n \cdot n \cdots n}$ . What do you think will be the limit?

Comment: The limit is $0$. L'Hospital's Rule won't work, for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yUGra.png) is the picture that the OP originally uploaded. @user71317 For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 2):

(a) 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{5 \cos((\frac{\pi}6))^n} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} 5 \cos((\frac{\pi}6))^n} = e^{5 \cos(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{\pi}6)^n)} = e^{5 \cdot 1} = e^5
$$

(b)
$$
 \frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdots n}{n\cdot n \cdot n} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
From here 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{n!}{n^n} = 0
$$
since 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0
$$

Comment: why is the limit of cos 1 and not -1? and how did you get 1/n for the second part?

Comment: $\cos 0 = 1$ and for the second part: $n \geq 2,3,4,\dots,n$ and therefore $\frac{2}{n},\dots,\frac{n}n \leq 1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^n=0.$$ 
Since $\cos x$ is continuous, it follows that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^n\right)=\cos(0)=1.$$ 
Since the function $e^x$ is continuous, it follows that the required limit is $e^5$.

For the second problem, please see the answer by UrošSlovenija.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one
(I've done this before btw),
$n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
=\prod_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)
$
so

$\begin{align}
n!^2 
&= \prod_{i=1}^n i(n+1-i)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n (i(n+1)-i^2)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n ((n+1)/2)^2-(n+1)/2)^2+ i(n+1)-i^2)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n ((n+1)/2)^2-((n+1)/2-i)^2)\\
&\le \prod_{i=1}^n ((n+1)/2)^2)\\
&= ((n+1)/2)^{2n}
\end{align}
$

so $n! < (\frac{n+1}{2})^{n}
$
and
$\frac{n!}{n^n}
\le (\frac{n+1}{2n})^{n}
$
and this $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.