# limits as n->infinity of: $(n^n)/n!$ and $ n^{(n^{0.5})}/(2^n)$

Tags: limits

How calculate the limits as n->infinity of:$$(n^n)/n!$$ and $$(n^{n^{0.5}})/(2^n)$$, my attempts: the second have to do something with : $$(n^{(n^{0.5}))}=2^{\log(\log n)}$$......log with base 2. The first I guess goes to infinity by intuition...

Comment: Stirling formula for 1st, use $a^b=\exp(b\log a)$ for 2nd part.

Comment: The first question is a duplicate: [Limit of factorial function: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!}.$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877305/limit-of-factorial-function-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnnn/877311)

Comment: Well, the first blows up as $n^n$ eventually grows much faster than $n!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For the second, write $n^{n^{1/2}}= 2^{n^{1/2}\log_2 n}$. Then 
$$
\frac{n^{n^{1/2}}}{2^n} = \frac{2^{n^{1/2}\log_2 n}}{2^n} = 2^{\sqrt{n}\log_2 n - n}.
$$
What can you say about the limit of $\sqrt{n}\log_2 n - n$?

For the first, either use Stirling's approximation; or if you cannot, the simpler fact that $$n^n = n^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot n^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
while
$$
n! = n(n-1)\dots\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)! < n^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)! < n^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$
where the inequalities come from termwise comparisons in the products.

Comment: how to prove who is bigger logn or n^0.5 ?

Comment: Hum... I assumed you could take for granted the fact that $\frac{\log^b n}{n^a}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, for any $a,b > 0$.

Comment: @user188750 Can you find the bigger of $e^n$ and $n^2$? The required result follows.