# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{(n+3)!}{n^n}}$

Tags: limits, factorial

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{(n+3)!}{n^n}}, n\in \mathbb N$$ I know that the limit is $0$ but how to prove it?

Comment: Use the Stirling's approximation.

Comment: It is $0$ because $n^{n}$ goes to infinity faster than $(n+3)!$

Comment: No need to use such heavy weapons. This has an elementary proof.

Comment: Dipok but how do you prove it?

Comment: Very similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn/61741#61741, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535226/limit-of-the-sequence-nn-n, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397866/limits-of-sequences-exponential-and-factorial, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877305/limit-of-factorial-function-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnnn You can find several relatively simple solutions there. Very probably similar ideas will work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{(n+3)!}{n^n}=2\cdot3\cdot\frac{4\cdot\ldots\cdot n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdot(n+3)}{n\cdot\ldots\cdot n}\le 6\cdot\frac4n\cdot\frac{n^{n-4}}{n^{n-4}}\cdot\frac{(2n)^3}{n^3}=6\cdot\frac4n\cdot8$$