# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^n}{3n!+3^n}$

Tags: limits, factorial

Could I please have a hint for finding the following limit?$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^n}{3n!+3^n}$$

Comment: HINT: try to consider $\lim_n \frac{3n!+3^n}{5n^n}$

Comment: Maybe try to apply [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Consider $\frac{6\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot 6}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6}$.

Comment: @Crostul: I am working on your suggestion and have reached a point where I must calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$.  How could I go about this in a rigorous way, please?

Comment: @CKKOY the limit you want you can get if you rewrite the potencies as exponentials and you will get that the limit is 1/n (so 0). exp(x*(log(x)-log(x+1))-log(x+1)) -> exp(-log(x)) -> 1/x

Comment: Some of these older posts might help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535226/limit-of-the-sequence-nn-n, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397866/limits-of-sequences-exponential-and-factorial

Comment: Especially this approach seems easy: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn/61741#61741

Answer (score 3):

Stirlings approximation of the factorial:
$$
\sqrt{2\,\pi\,n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$
5 and 3 are constant factors so put them before the limit. Now we have to concern ourselves with:
$$
\frac{5}{3}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^n}{\sqrt{2\,\pi\,n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n+3^n} = \frac{5}{3\,\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^n}{\sqrt{n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}+3^n} = \frac{5}{3\,\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n}+\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^n}\\
= \frac{5}{3\,\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\dfrac{e^n}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the limit diverges as consider the inverse of limit i.e 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3n! + 3^n}{5n^n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3}{5}*\frac{3^n}{n^n}$$ tends to zero as 3/n tends to zero as n tends to infinity.
Also $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3}{5}*\frac{n!}{n^n}$$ also tends to zero as $$ e\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \leqslant n! \leqslant ne\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ and using sandwich theorem on this we get the total limit tends to zero so the actual limit given diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Use *equivalents*:

First $3n!+3^n=3n!+o(n!)$ so: $$ 3n!+3^n\sim_\infty3n!\sim_\infty 3\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac n{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n$$
and
$$\frac{5n^n}{3n!+3^n}\sim_\infty\frac{\mathrm e^n}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty.$$

Comment: I think that the very last part of your answer should read $\frac{5n^n}{3n!+3^n}\sim_\infty\frac{\mathrm e^n}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty.$  Am I correct?

Comment: @CKKOY I think it should be $\infty$ as well

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for pointing the Freudian slip :o) Corrected now.